# How to read values separated by semi colon in a sharepoint user profile?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a field named Responsibility in a user profile on sharepoint site which contains value like "abc; def; ghi". I want to read these values into an array. 
When i am using [propertyconstants.responsibility].value only abc is being read. How to read abc, def and ghi separately?

My code is:

```
string xpUser = up[PropertyConstants.Responsibility].Value.ToString();
string[] expUser = xpUser.Split(';');
```

Comment: Can you use `string.Split()` ?

Comment: I have tried this thing too but the major problem is that in spUser only abc is being stored.

Comment: `contains value like "abc; def; ghi"` - where are these values ? in a string type field/property ? if so then you can use `string.Split(';')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I finally was able to find the solution which was

```
 var strUser = up.GetProfileValueCollection(PropertyConstants.Responsibility);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here you have something like this

```
string xpUser =  "abc; def; ghi";
```

And you want abe, def & ghi separately then do like this

```
string[] arrayUser = xpUser.Split(';');
foreach(string user in arrayUser)
{
   //Do what you want with **user** , now this user will have values that you want 1 by 1
   //if you see the value of user, 1st time you will get abc, 2nd time def , 3rd time ghi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to imply that you want to split by the token "; " (since you said you wanted "abc" rather than " abc")

Here is a unit test that demonstrates doing this.

```
 [Test]
 public void SplitStringByString()
 {
    string input = "abc; def; ghi";
    string[] expected = new[] {"abc", "def", "ghi"};

    var result = input.Split(new [] { "; " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    Assert.That(result, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
 }
```